# How to override class?

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't the following gradientappy class override settings in stripe-button-el class?

Also, is there a better way to do this than using all the *!important* attributes?

CSS:

```
.gradientapply {
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #46A1DA 0%, #3083B8 100%) !important;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #46A1DA 0%, #3083B8 100%) !important;
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #46A1DA 0%, #3083B8 100%) !important;
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #46A1DA 0%, #3083B8 100%) !important;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #46A1DA 0%, #3083B8 100%) !important;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="pay()" class="gradientapply stripe-button-el" style="visibility: visible;width:270px;height:72px;">
<span style="display: block; min-height: 72px;font-size:32px;padding-top:20px;">Buy Now</span></button>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5tyhcbwo/

Comment: Write the `gradientapply`class after the `stripe` class in your css and apply it later in the class attribute.

Comment: Where do you specify stripe-button-el?

Comment: It does override `.stripe-button-el` for me.

Comment: @BoltClock is definitely right. Paddy: In the button element.

Comment: @BoltClock Let's explain why. The `!important` css tag, http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Show your .stripe-button-el css selector please.

Comment: @JoshKG: just follow the link in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `.stripe-button-el span` has a background applied... since it is on top of your `.gradientapply` class, you can't see it's background. You have to remove or override the background on `.stripe-button-el span`.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tyhcbwo/1/) just adding `.stripe-button-el span { background: none; }`.

> Also, is there a better way to do this than using all the !important
>   attributes?

Unfortunately, no. Without the `!important`, the `.stripe-button-el` class will be applied.

Comment: It's an external class so I don't have control over modifying it.

Comment: Add .gradientapply span { ... not only .gradientapply

Comment: @4thSpace, I updated it showing JUST the override code... without you having to affect the external code.

Comment: You are just saying to add this additional span to the class?  That is working.

Comment: Correct. Alternatively, you could just apply your `background`s to that `span` instead, and I *believe* you won't have to use `!important`s in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't hide the span?

```
.gradientapply span {opacity: 0}
.ltie9 .gradientapply span {filter: alpha(opacity=0)}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tyhcbwo/2/)